# How to Use HTML inside PHP (Show only if value exists)

Tags: php, html

I have the following code on my ecommerce product description tabs so that I can enter in all the information one field at a time without having to preformat my product descriptions in Excel with HTML.

```
<?php echo the_field('color');?><br>
<?php echo the_field('product_info');?><br>
<?php echo the_field('product_size');?><br>
<?php echo the_field('product_size2');?><br>
<?php echo the_field('product_size3');?><br>
```

Unfortunately this isn't helpful because the 
 tags outside of the PHP will leave blank lines in cases when no value exists for these fields. How can I incorporate the 
 tags inside the PHP so that they're used only when a value exists?

I'm clearly new to PHP (and coding in general), so I really appreciate anyone's help. Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to have like an array with all the information or something? If so, why not use an array? You can parse the array and all the empty values will not be displayed

Comment: You can use `if(isset())` or `if(!empty())` to check if they are set or not empty. http://nl1.php.net/isset and http://nl1.php.net/empty

Comment: `<?php echo (empty(the_field('product_info')) ?  '' : the_field('product_info').'<br/>'); ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`if(get_field('field_name') != "")
 {
    echo '<p>' . get_field('field_name') . '</p>';
 }`

Should work for you

Comment: or !empty(get_field('field_name'))

Comment: That is a much cleaner way! I must use that next time

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
<?php echo empty(trim(the_field('color'))) ? '' : the_field('color') . '<br>'; ?>
```

And repeat the same pattern for every field.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what your `the_field` function does and how "heavy" it is, this should avoid unnecessary duplication of the calls to both test and output the result.

```
<?php if($color = the_field('color')): ?>
    <?php echo $color; ?><br>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($product_info = the_field('product_info')): ?>
    <?php echo $product_info; ?><br>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($product_size = the_field('product_size')): ?>
    <?php echo $product_size; ?><br>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($product_size2 = the_field('product_size2')): ?>
    <?php echo $product_size2; ?><br>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($product_size3 = the_field('product_size3')): ?>
    <?php echo $product_size3; ?><br>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Brendan! This is great except the <br> tags don't seem to be having any effect no matter how many I use. Is this correct?

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: Use this:**

```
<?php echo (the_field('color') != '') ? the_field('color') . '<br>' : ''; ?>
<?php echo (the_field('product_info') != '') ? the_field('product_info') . '<br>' : ''; ?>
<?php echo (the_field('product_size') != '') ? the_field('product_size') . '<br>' : ''; ?>
<?php echo (the_field('product_size2') != '') ? the_field('product_size2') . '<br>' : ''; ?>
<?php echo (the_field('product_size3') != '') ? the_field('product_size3') . '<br>' : ''; ?>
```